# Angular 2+ i18n dialects/accents

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular8, language-translation, angular-i18n

Let's say we set up and use the Angular i18n-tags similar to the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/i18n):

```
<div i18n>Hello World</div>
```

We generate our translations using `ng xi18n --i18nFormat=xlf`

So far so good, now we want to start generating specific translations for dialects/accents, e.g. de_AT (austrian german). In our application there are very few of those. Therefor to keep the translation files maintainable, we don't want to generate a whole new `.xlf` for every dialect, but use a basic `messages.de.xlf` and somehow divert the accents/dialects from there.

First thought for a first step was to generate a new `messages.de_AT.xlf` containing only those specific translation, e.g:

```
<trans-unit id="5d9f8[...]f66d3e" datatype="html" approved="yes">
  <source>Hello World</source>
  <target state="translated">Griasdi Welt</target>
  <context-group purpose="location">
    <context context-type="sourcefile">src/app/hello-world.component.ts</context>
    <context context-type="linenumber">16</context>
  </context-group>
</trans-unit>
```

But no idea how to do that and what to do then. So I am looking for some best practice tricks or example projects. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Angular needs a complete translation file to build the project in a given language. What you could do is create a `messages.de_AT.xlf.partial` file with only specific AT translations, then find/create some tool to merge your base German translations  `messages.de.xlf` with `messages.de_AT.xlf.partial` , resulting in a complete `messages.de_AT.xlf` file

Comment: Dear @sevic, this question is already 2 years ago  Did you found a way to solve your problem? Did you build the tool described in the accepted answer? This seems like such a common problem.  I can‘t believe there isn‘t anybody who solved it yet.... (I‘m a german, too)

Comment: @wottpal so far i did not put any more effort into this issue. I reserved some time on this weekend to have a look, maybe I manage to come up with a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular needs a complete translation file to build the project in a given language.

What you could do is create a `messages.de_AT.xlf.partial` file with only AT specific translations, then find/create some tool to merge your base German translations `messages.de.xlf` with `messages.de_AT.xlf.partial`, resulting in a complete `messages.de_AT.xlf`.

I had a quick look and could not find any ready tool to do the merge, but since xlf files are actually XML files, you could probably write your own script that does that.